# MS SQL DRIVER ERROR while connecting with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have annaconda 3.7 installed, using pycharm IDE. installed `brew install --env  msodbcsql17 mssql-tools` and getting below error when connecting to my ms sql server:

`Setting Env Vars for TEST ENV
Trying to connect to DB. Args: use_local=False, db_path=<path to db.sql>
 *** connected with Engine(mssql+pyodbc:<userid and pass>/test_db?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server)
DB Configured (but not yet connected).`

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: collate_byname::collate_byname failed to construct for UTF-8**

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Any help would be appreciated